# How to retrieve DataTable value to <div> in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET, I am making a search box in my application.

For example: if a user enters "abc" in the textbox, then the textbox will fetch data from the database which starts with "abc".  I am passing this data to `DataTable`.

It works properly,

Here is my code snippet:

```
DataTable result = new DataTable();`

protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConsString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    conn.Open();

    string query = string.Format("SELECT DISTINCT Scrip FROM dbo.SearchBoxData where Scrip Like '{0}%'", TextBox1.Text);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    result.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

    conn.Close();
}
```

Now I want to retrieve all this data in my `<div>` tag.  How should I retrieve and display?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As I see you're going achieve your goal by making postback everytime text changes in text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably better use a databound control, like the ListView (or the GridView) control. This way you can create nice layouts you want with the data in the datatable.

For instance, a ListView could be used:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvwItems" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="plhItems">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div>
             <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhItems" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <%# Eval("ColumnFromDataTable")%>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

In your code behind you can then do:

```
lvwItems.DataSource = result;
lvwItems.DataBind();
```

Remark: code is just out of my head, could contain some errors

Comment: dude, you rock it's working, but i am unable to select, particular cell of listView. ? give me this ans and i will accept your ans..

Comment: use the ListView SelectedTemplate for that. See this example for more information: http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2009/12/listview-selecteditemtemplate-how-to.html

Comment: <SelectedItemTemplate>
    <div>
       <%# Eval("Scrip")%>
    </div>  i tried this but unable to select, plz help me..

Comment: Maybe it is selecting, but you just don't see it. You should change f.i. the style of the div when selected. see the msdn for a quick example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selecteditemtemplate.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You should use a databound control like a ListView or GridView. I'd recommend creating a separate control to hold one row in the list and using the RowDataBound method to assign the row data. Example of using ListView's ItemDatabound event - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx

On a side note your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection